Deploy a custom prometheus exporter on a application lost host
Im trying to deploy a custom app exporter on our Linux server as a end-point then register in prometheus, unable to bring up a service on localhost
https://github.com/devon-mar/tacacs-exporter
can anyone assist in creating a systemd service and expose on localhost endpoint.
[Unit]
Description=TACACS Exporter
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/tacacs-exporter_0.1.0_linux_amd64

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

systemd[1]: Started TACACS Exporter.
systemd[1]: tacacs_exporter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
tacacs_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

